# How do you access SQL database from GWT?

Tags: java, sql, gwt, client-server, jetty

I've read some articles on the Internet that this is not possible. To communicate own SQL database that is located on other server from GWT application. Jetty doesn't allow it.

I found a way how to perform it but it's not very cosy. I have client and server part inside GWT. The server has to communicate with MySQL database on localhost. So I've written an ant script to build a war that I can launch on Apache Tomcat server. It works perfectly there but I'm not able to debug the code effectively.

Do you have some advices how to perform this task? I was thinking of writing the clienty only in GWT and find some waz how to communicate my own server written outside the GWT. I've found Apache Thrift for GWT but this edited library of thrift seem not to work properly.

Thank you very much for your answers:)

Comment: "Jetty doesn't allow it." I suppose you're talking about the embedded server in GWT's DevMode. In which case, you probably enabled "App Engine" in Eclipse by mistake (which indeed restricts what you can do on the server-side, to mimic the actually limitations of Google's hosting).

Comment: no :) its not possible. I have the server side GWT and this one has to communicate with the MySQL database. The problem is that Jetty (the application server of GWT) refuses connections to own databases.

Comment: so it normally works fine if i disable this option ?

Comment: ok now i disabled the GAE and gonna try it

Comment: well it works so finally there was problem on my side thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to communicate with a database from a GWT application. The client side has to call the methods of the server via GWT-RPC, which can communicate with any database.

Maybe Jetty does not support it (have not tested it personally) but you can develop your web application using Apache too. There you can access the database the same way as from any web application:

You will need the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar` file (downloadable from: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ ), and restart the server added to the `$CATALINA_HOME/common/lib` directory.

OR added to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your web application.

You can find tutorials online of how to develop an application using Tomcat instead of Jetty. For example: https://wiki.auckland.ac.nz/display/BeSTGRID/Deploying+GWT+to+Tomcat+in+Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Reshi, stop and think about how applications really work. Nobody provides web pages with javascript to read/write databases, that would be crazy and unsecure. Servers are always in themiddle of all communication in this case. You need to create services that run inside your server, one of these services will be a database layer.

Javascript cant create network connections and read/write binary data, thus it would be insane to attempt to get the gwt compiler to compile any jdbc drvier and more.

Comment: I know that I can't access the database directly from client :) My project in GWT has a GWT client side and GWT server.

Comment: I wanted to access MySQL database from server part of GWT application but Jetty (the built in application server) refused the connection to MySQL database. And I read that it's not possible to access your own database servers from GWT server under Jetty. That the only way is to use Google's DataSource. Now I 'm working this way: I build own .war file each time I need to test something in my project. And deploy it into Tomcat.

Comment: But if I have to do it 6 times per hour it 's a lot. So I was trying to find some different way how to access the database from GWT using Jetty or not using Jetty (doesnt matter).

Answer (score 0):

Jetty does NOT stop us from connecting to a database. All you have to do is to follow the MVP model way. Although MVP is better bet against all hurdles, at a minimal point, you would have to try not having SQL code on the client package.